# Include a JSP (which contains CSS link) in another JSP

Tags: html, css, jsp

I have a JSP page which contains CSS links as follows. This is the complete code in the JSP(a.jsp):

```
<link href="/aspenet/resources/css/StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/aspenet/resources/css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

I include a.jsp inside b.jsp as follows:

```
<head>
   <title>Title</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="resources/css/jquery/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.6.custom.css" />     

   <jsp:include page="a.jsp"/>

   <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/js/jquery/jquery-1.7.2.min.js">   </script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
</head>
```

But the styles of the default.css does not reflect in b.jsp when I run the application. Help me to resolve the issue.

Comment: Include those two style-sheets StyleSheet.css and default.css also in a.jsp

Comment: You mean to include in b.jsp? If so, actually I need to use a.jsp in many other JSPs to avoid duplication.

Comment: a.jsp and b.jsp both are on same path??

Comment: @Manjeet Brar Yes, they are in the same path

Comment: Remove /aspenet/ from /aspenet/resources/css/StyleSheet.css

Comment: Thanks @Manjeet Brar. It works. The path should be like this: 
resources/css/StyleSheet.css (without the initial '/' character)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use following code in your a.jsp page.

```
<link href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/css/StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

`request.getContextPath()`- return root path of your application so let say your application name is **demo** then it will try to find `demo/css/xyz.css` file.

Hope it may help you.!!

Comment: Yes, I tried to manually adding the absolute path. But it didn't work.

Comment: Don't try to add absolute path manually instead  use <%=request.getContextPath()%>